# Can a swf make a https call on the same domain but to different paths?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, https

If my project is hosted on `https://www.example.com/directoryA/myswf.swf` can it make a HTTPS call to `https://www.example.com/directoryB/another/directory` or will it be blocked for not being in the same path?

I'm trying to debug an issue and when running on file system it works fine but uploading to the server I'm getting a 2032 stream error. I'm checking all the URLs are correct but maybe this is a cross domain issue with HTTPS?

---

**UPDATE:**
The reason it was not working or seemed to be working intermittently was actually because of a 413 Request Entity Too Large error on the server.

```
<title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Request Entity Too Large</h1>
The requested resource<br />/path/in/another/directory/<br />
does not allow request data with POST requests, or the amount of data provided in
the request exceeds the capacity limit.
</body></html>
```

That's why it would appear to work on file but then not on http was not because of the protocol (thanks @organis) but because when I was testing on the server I was using real test data (large) while testing locally it was small amount of test data.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error

Comment: There shouldn't be any security restrictions. The fact you're getting IO error rather that security error means that SWF incorrectly resolves the (possible relative) URL.

Comment: You're right. It was a 413 Request Entity Too Large. I've updated the post.

Comment: So now it's a totally HTTP server error, not related to Flash?

Comment: Yeah I think so. I'm not hundred percent sure but it appears to be related to HTTPS. Have to run more tests but it appears when switching to HTTPS SSL the post size is much smaller. I'll try to keep this post updated with my findings.

Comment: Seems like a server variable: https://github.com/thinserver/OpenLawyers/issues/1